# Unhandled Lockdown error (-4) ipod 4G

Tags: 10.10, ipod

Running Ubuntu 10.10 getting this error as soon as I connect my iPod 4G running IOS 5.0.1.
When I open Nautilus, I can see the iPod icon, but same error appears when I try and open the ipod.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has already been solved. You can check more out here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/795475

Comment: Sorry, where is the actual fix for this one from that link?

Answer (score 0):

They've fixed this bug for every recent version of Ubuntu except Maverick. [They say they aren't going to fix it for Maverick since it's now unsupported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/795475/comments/69).

Your best bet is to upgrade Ubuntu.